# Abp replacing method of auto controller does not work

Tags: controller, overriding, auto, abp

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Customizing-Application-Modules-Overriding-Services I used this documentation to override the endpoint od auto generated controller.
This is my code, which gives response 500. And also I cannot use override on that method, because most likely AbpController is not what I need, though in the documenation i could not find any info about which type of controler to use in case of auto controllers.

```
        [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
    [ExposeServices(typeof(AbpApplicationConfigurationController))]
    public class ProductController : AbpController
    {
        private readonly IProductAppService _productAppService;
        public ProductController(IProductAppService productAppService)
        {
            _productAppService = productAppService;
        }
        [HttpPut("api/app/product/{id}")]
        public Task<ProductDto> UpdateAsync(Guid id, CreateUpdateProductDto createUpdateProductDto)
        {
            var a = 3;
            return new Task<ProductDto>(() => new ProductDto());
        }
    }
```

------------------------

Comment: Your reasoning to replace `AbpApplicationConfigurationController` with `ProductController` doesn't make sense.

Please explain what are you trying to override with what?

Comment: @gterdem I understand that it does not make sense. DO you know which controller I should override? I auto configured controllers, it created a lot of endpoints, including crud endpoints for my Product entity. And i want to override one of this method, specifically Update.